# mvn verify failure in okhttp-tests

Tags: maven, okhttp

I am trying to verify my build of the okhttp library.
Running 'mvn -X clean verify' on a recent download of the master branch.
I get the following error:

```
[matthias@oc0105085538 surefire-reports]$ more okhttp3.ConnectionCoalescingTest.txt
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: okhttp3.ConnectionCoalescingTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 12, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 5.237 sec <<< FAILURE! - in okhttp3.ConnectionCoalescingTest
prefersExistingCompatible(okhttp3.ConnectionCoalescingTest)  Time elapsed: 0.598 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<3> but was:<2>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:631)
    at okhttp3.ConnectionCoalescingTest.prefersExistingCompatible(ConnectionCoalescingTest.java:256)
```

Comment: There should be an error higher up in the output if you include more of the logs.  Also this is probably more relevant as a bug report to the project https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues if reproducible.

Comment: Try to run in debug mode with `mvn -X clean verify`

Answer (score 0):

ok this was fixed in okhttp 3.9.0
Thanks everyone for your help.